# Navigating fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to the android. I've an activity with 5 fragments and I've used **addTobackStack** so that I can move to the previous fragments when back button is clicked. It does the work but I want to call the functions in which I've been replacing the fragments when back button is pressed.
Any help?

Here is the code.

Dashboard.java

```
package com.example.sheikhspc.design;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView home1, subs1, noti1,settings1,date1;
Fragment frag = null;
TextView home, subs,noti,set,date;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
    home1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home1);
    subs1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.subs1);
    noti1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.noti1);
    settings1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.settings1);
    date1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.date1);
    frag = new dashboard1();
    home = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hometv);
    subs = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.substv);
    noti = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.notitv);
    set = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.settingstv);
    date = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.datestv);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container1,frag).commit();

    Toolbar mytoolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.mytoolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mytoolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
    home.setTextColor(0xFF000000);









}


public void dbfragment(View view)
{
    if(frag != null)
    {


          home1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_icon_black)  ome1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_icon_black) );
home.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
          subs1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.subscription_ic on));
           noti1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.noti_icon));
        settings1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.setting_icon));


         date1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.date_icon));
        date1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.d))    
        frag = new dashboard1();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container1,frag);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();




    }
}
public void dates(View view)
{
    if(frag != null)
    {
        home1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_icon));
        subs1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.subscription_icon));
        noti1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.noti_icon));
        settings1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.setting_icon));
        date1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.date_icon_black));
        date.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Available Dates");
        frag = new AvailableDates();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container1,frag);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}

public void subscription(View view)
{
    if (frag != null)
    {
        home1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_icon));
        subs1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.subscription_icon_black));
        noti1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.noti_icon));
        settings1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.setting_icon));
        date1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.date_icon));
        subs.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Subscriptions");
        frag = new Subscription();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container1,frag);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
public void noti(View view)
{
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Notifications");
    if (frag != null)
    {
        home1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_icon));
        subs1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.subscription_icon));
        noti1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.noti_icon_black));
        settings1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.setting_icon));
        noti.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
        date1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.date_icon));
        frag = new Notification();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container1,frag);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
public void settings(View view)
{
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Settings");
    if (frag != null)
    {
        set.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
        home1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_icon));
        subs1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.subscription_icon));
        noti1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.noti_icon));
        settings1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.setting_ion_black));
        date1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.date_icon));
        frag = new Settings();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container1,frag);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
public void signout(View view)
{
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ){
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }


}
}
```

Activity_dashboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_dashboard"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"


android:background="@color/white"
tools:context="com.example.sheikhspc.design.dashboard">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:layout_below="@id/mytoolbar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/headrl"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        tools:ignore="NotSibling">


<!--            <Button
            android:text=""
            android:background="@drawable/subscription_icon_black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/notificationbtn"
            android:onClick="subscription"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/adbtn"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/adbtn"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp" />-->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/home_icon_black"
            android:onClick="dbfragment"
            android:id="@+id/home1"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Home"
            android:layout_below="@+id/home1"
            android:id="@+id/hometv"

            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/date_icon"
            android:onClick="dates"
            android:id="@+id/date1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dates"
            android:layout_below="@+id/date1"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/datestv"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home1"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/noti_icon"
            android:onClick="noti"
            android:id="@+id/noti1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Notifications"
            android:layout_below="@+id/noti1"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/notitv"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date1"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/subscription_icon"
            android:onClick="subscription"
            android:id="@+id/subs1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/noti1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Subscription"
            android:layout_below="@+id/noti1"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/substv"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/noti1"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/setting_icon"
            android:onClick="settings"
            android:id="@+id/settings1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/subs1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Settings"
            android:layout_below="@+id/noti1"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/settingstv"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/subs1"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/logout_icon"
            android:onClick="signout"
            android:id="@+id/signout1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/settings1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Logout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/noti1"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/settings1"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>


        <!--<Button
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/adbtn"
            android:onClick="dates"

            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/date_icon_black"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dbbtn" />

        <Button
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dbbtn"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"

            android:background="@drawable/home_icon_black"

            android:onClick="dbfragment"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />-->

    </RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/headrl"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/Black"
            android:id="@+id/container1">


        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can implement the [FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener.html) and call your methods there depending upon which fragment is currently in the back stack. As I understand, currently the methods are called via touch interactions like button clicks. You wouldn't be able to do this on backstack change and need to figure out an alternate way. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Where to implement this  FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener and how I can check that which fragment is in the back stack.

Comment: Yes exactly these methods are called when clicked on an imageview

Comment: See if my answer helps?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the `FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener` and call your methods there depending upon which fragment is currently in the back stack. As I understand, currently the methods are called via touch interactions like button clicks. You wouldn't be able to do this on backstack change and need to figure out an alternate way.

You need to implement `OnBackStackChangedListener` in the activity. Better do the following in `onCreate` in your `dashboard.java`:

```
fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
```

Then override `onBackStackChanged` in your `dashboard.java` like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    //get the current fragment being displayed
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container1);
    if (fragment instanceof AvailableDates) {
        //do your stuff
    } else if (fragment instanceof Subscription) {
        //do other stuff
    } //and so on for each fragment
 }
```

You can make different implementations for your `onClick` methods like thus:

```
public void dates(View view)
{
    if(frag != null)
    {
      openAvailableDates();
     }
}
```

and then implement `openAvailableDates` thus:

```
void openAvailableDates() {
    home1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_icon));
    subs1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.subscription_icon));
    noti1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.noti_icon));
    settings1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.setting_icon));
    date1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.date_icon_black));
    date.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Available Dates");
    frag = new AvailableDates();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container1,frag);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

and so on for your other methods and then call these new methods from `onBackStackChanged`.

One more tip. It's not good practice to name your classes starting with a lowercase letter. It's best to refactor `dashboard.java` to `Dashboard.java`.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you Ishita. I'm on it. One more Question
how can I call the method in the if condition as each method have a View Parameter.

Comment: I've searched it but got nothing

Comment: That's exactly what I meant when I said you need to figure out an alternate way. If you do not need to use the view inside the method at all, you could pass a `null`, I suppose. But I don't know if that would be advisable. At any rate, try once and see.

Comment: yup. It doesn't work that way. passing null is a bad practice and I've using views in my functions so this is not working for me.

Thank You btw

Comment: I checked your code and you're not really using the views passed as _arguments_ to your methods. Did you try passing null?